# A firefox addon to access blocked sites?

Tags: firefox, internet

Well, I am having a really slow network connection (Wi-Fi) which often disconnects. If this was not enough, half of the sites of blocked with OpenDNS.com. Funny (and insane) thing is that they even blocked stackoverflow and gmail.

Till now I was using Ultrasurf but Its got problems of its own. I wont get into explaining them. I want to know a firefox addon for proxy browsing which has a database of its own, and can be enabled or disabled by click of a button. I found FoxyProxy but I think it is way too complicated than what I want.

Comment: Change the DNS server, simple and easy.

Comment: @HackToHell: To make my self clear, the WiFi connection is provided by my institute. Though, its pathetic its all I can use. Everytime I access it redirects to me OpenDNS.com. I don't think I can change DNS server anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change the DNS servers you use. You can assign your own DNS servers for use on your computer. The only necesary detail to use your institute's net is the gateway, and of course being on the right subnet.

I could provide you with instructions, if you could tell me what your OS is.

Comment: Windows 7. (Filling with absurditiy because it wont allow less that 15 characters.. :D)

Comment: Do you mean changing the DNS servers in the connection properties?

Comment: To change the DNS settings in Windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings. you could use third-party DNS servers, for example many people use Google's public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/. However your institute may block third-party DNS servers in which case you need to use proxy or VPN.

Comment: @lupincho: Cant access net with the google's public DNS. Now, to the original question: Any good addons?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought -- if they use OpenDNS, most likely they filter DNS requests. Sorry, don't know about addons, but you could try VPN (assuming that they don't filter that too). These are mostly paid, though.

Comment: Well, that might be the reason to use OpenDNS. I remember seeing they had a service where they allowed custom filtering for companies.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use Resurrect Page to source blocked pages from various caches (Google, Yahoo, CoralCDN, archive.org, etc.).

Comment: Well, that addon does'nt sync a bit with what I need.